# changing slimscroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css, slimscroll

Is there a way to move scrollbar position on initialisation when using slimscroll? I found it's possible to do this using jQuery on native scrollbar with "scrollTop", but don't see how would I be able to do it using slimscroll. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/c8d3ohue/

Basically I want the first div to be scrolled down on init, like in this picture.

[image: end-result]

My code:

```
<div class="slimScroll" style="overflow-y:auto;height:200px;width:250px">
    <div class="child-height-1" style="height:50%;overflow:hidden;position:relative">
        <div class="child-content" style="height:300px;background-color:lightgreen">asd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-height-2" style="height:50%;overflow:hidden;position:relative">
        <div class="child-content" style="height:300px;background-color:lightyellow">asd</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-scroll/1.3.2/slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        new slimScroll($('.child-height-1')[0]);
        new slimScroll($('.child-height-2')[0]);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` instead of `slimscroll.min.js`, you can do this like this.

For your same HTML above, in the document ready you can do like this,

```
var itemContainer1 = $(".child-height-1");
itemContainer1.slimScroll({
    height: '200px',
    start: 'bottom',
    alwaysVisible: true
}); 

var itemContainer2 = $(".child-height-2");
itemContainer2.slimScroll({
    height: '200px',
    start: 'top',
    alwaysVisible: true
});
```

See a fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/uypabr6o/

How it looks,

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, it worked, ended up using this slimScroll version, thank you!

Comment: Hello @brgs, I am glad my answer was helpful. Thanks for the up vote and accepting. Cheers.